# How do you translate "vorko" in English

Tags: single-word-requests

As with some other words, like *pravi*, *provi*, *pruvi*, the case of *verko* and *vorko* makes morphologically apparent a semantic link with a vowel change, as it often occurs in Semitics languages.

So, I would translate *verko* with *work*. That's probably the closest single word counterpart, although the semantic fields of each term greatly differ. Now, I recently discovered *vorko*, that PIV define as *Grava konstruaĵo (aŭtovojo, ponto, tunelo ks)*. Is there a better suited translation than *work* for *vorko*, so one might translate a discourse containing both *verko* and *vorko* in English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vorko` stems from the English `work` as `verko` from the German `Werk`. Both mean something like "master piece" in the original languages. Also both mean `labori` (Low German/Dutch). The Esperanto definition of `verko` is quite limited, hence the very rarely used `vorko`.

Distinguishing the two "works" means looking for synonyms:

```
vorko = monument
verko = writings, piece
verkaro = oeuvre
```

Comment: Vorko is not monument - not according to the definition listed in the OP.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander true, I thought of _monumental work_, but that would be ambiguous again. I have sought for a more narrow term.

Comment: The definition in the OP translates to **important building project such as an expressway, bridge, or tunnel.** This certainly is not well described by "monument", which is a structure "erected to commemorate a famous or notable person or event" - or perhaps a grave stone.

Answer (score 5):

"Public work" (singular of "public works.")

Of course, context is everything.

Answer (score 1):

The word *vorko* is a *neologismo* and since we already have two roots, *labori* and *verki*, for different kinds of acts of work, there is little excuse to introduce yet another work-related root. As Tomaso Alexander already pointed out *vorko* is used for "a public work", which denotes something that is constructed. Therefore the [*bona lingvo*](http://bonalingvo.net/index.php/Ssv:_V) expression is *konstruaĵo, konstruado* or *konstruejo* depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

In French: un ouvrage d'art. Ekzemple: La nova fervojo inter Liono kaj Milano necesigos la konstruon de pluraj vorkoj.